# How is the best way to generate a calendar table in PowerCenter?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I must generate a table of calendar dates from dateIni to dateEnd in Powercenter Designer.

dateIni is is fixed, for example '2013-01-01'
dateEnd is sysdate + 'n' months

I'm trying to generate from a java tranformation, that can generate several dynamic rows but needs an input row and I do not have any input... it there any other better approach using seq generator???

As an example table content result must be

```
date
=======
'2013-01-01'
'2013-01-02'
'2013-01-03'
...
...
'2016-03-10'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a single input row from any source into the Java transformation and then generate rows with consecutive dates in a loop.

You can create a simple table with two columns - dateIni and dateEnd. It will contain a single row that will both kickstart the Java code and provide configuration for the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

When working with an Oracle database you can also use the following query in your source qualifier:

```
  SELECT  level
  FROM    dual
  CONNECT BY
          level <= 1000 --(or any other number)
```

This will generate 1000 rows.

With an Expression-transformation you can change this into dates:

```
  ADD_TO_DATE(to_date('20190101','yyyymmdd'), 'DAY',Level)
```